# how to save a variable include image into isolate storage in windowsphone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

i've been doing a essay about windowsphone. i created a address variable include a uri to add a image into address. There is a error when i use Isolate storage to save data. I don't know why. 
Please help me!
Thank you so much.

```
class Address
{
   private string name;
   private Uri icon;
   .....
}
```

......

```
public void save()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xmlwritersetting = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlwritersetting.Indent = true;
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myisolatedstiragefile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            if (myisolatedstiragefile.FileExists(filename))
            {
                myisolatedstiragefile.DeleteFile(filename);
            }

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myisolatedstiragefile))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Adress>));
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlwritersetting))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, listadress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error? On which line? Have you marked the `Adress` class as serializable?

Comment: Please explain the error. What kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult for me to understand your question, but I'll try.  You really should indicate what error you specifically get in the debugger and where it occurs.

But just by looking, it seems that you might be trying to use the XmlSerializer to write binary image data to iso-storage and that probably won't work.  You can find many examples of using iso-storage for various purposes including writing image files here:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

For example, it shows that you can save a JPG image to isolated storage by doing this:

```
    // Create a filename for JPEG file in isolated storage.
            String tempJPEG = "logo.jpg";             
    // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files. 
           using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(tempJPEG))                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
            }  
               IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(tempJPEG); 
                StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
                Uri uri = new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative);
                sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
                 BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                 // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                 //wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);                fileStream.Close();
            }
```

Comment: sory, my english not good...hehe. I have a Address variable. and i want to add a image into it. I used Uri to do that. Error at here:       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Address>)); and error messeage: {"There was an error reflecting property 'Icon'."}   I've just read artices in windowsphonegeek but don't have solution yet. Thanks Dan Colasan ti for your help.